# select max count in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a query that returns the max salary earned by numerous employees and how many people earned the max amount. for example if $20000 was the max amount earned by all employees, and 2 employees earned that, I want to return (20000, 2).

`select count(*) as count, max(months*salary) as maxSalary from employees;`

this returns the max salary, but returns the count of all employees in the table, I tried using count(max(months*salary)), but that doesn't work, is there a function that can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think aggregation and `limit`:

```
select (months * salary) as Salary, count(*) as count
from employees
group by months * salary
order by months * salary desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: I'll chalk this one down as a W for you

Answer (score 2):

```
 select months*salary, count(*) from employees
 where months*salary = (select max(months*salary)  from employees)
 group by months*salary;
```